# How to attr one link to multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am not really sure if the title points to my question but:
I would like to show two different elements(contents and images) at the same time with one link.. It s kinda content and image slider so if you click link1 attr content1 and image1, if you click on link2 attr content2 and image2 and so on..

That way I can attract boxes but how would I call images too?

```
$(".box").hide();
$(".box:first").show();

$("a").click(function() {
    var activeLink = $(this).attr("href"); 
    $("a").removeClass("active");
    $(".box").hide();
    $(activeLink).slideDown("normal");
    return false;
});
```

I have come so far..
http://jsfiddle.net/2GR3W/2/

Thnx in advance!

Comment: Try assigning unique ID for each element that you want to hide/show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Text Box
    $(".box, .img").hide();
    $(".box:first,.img:first").show();
    $("a").click(function (e) {
        var idx=$(this).index();
        e.preventDefault();
        var activeLink = $(this).attr("href");
        $("a").removeClass("active");
        $(".box, .img").hide();
        $('.container div').eq(idx).slideDown("normal");
        $('.container img').eq(idx).slideDown("normal");
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2GR3W/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try refactoring your image ID references to follow a convention named after your link href values.

```
<img id="box3-img" class="img"  src="asd.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="img3"/>
```

Then you can treat the 'href' attr value as a mere prefix against the ID for the images:

```
$(activeLink + "-img").show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2GR3W/5/

Comment: That sounds interesting! but img id = box3-img is not a id name here? I don't really get refactoring img id with a convention??..

Answer (score 0):

My solution for you is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.links').on('click','a',function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
            $('.links a').removeClass('active')
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.container').find('.box, img').hide();
            $('.container').find('.box').eq($(this).index()).slideDown('normal');
            $('.container').find('img').eq($(this).index()).fadeIn('normal');
        }
    }); 

});

$(window).load(function(){
    $('.links').find('a:nth-child(1)').trigger('click');
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2GR3W/7/

With this code you can put infinites `<a/>`, `<div class="box"/>` and `<img/>`, it will always find the `.box` and the `img` in the same 'order' and show it